# How can drawString method be used for writing diagonal way

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio-2005, gdi, drawstring

I am using c# 2005 i want to write string diagonally on image. But by default c# provides the option to write horizontally or vertically.

how we write diagonally?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do a  [Graphics.rotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform.aspx) before the drawString call. Don't forget to reverse the change afterwards, as Phil Wright points out.

Comment: You can have lotsa fun adding a semi-random transform for every line in a text editor  :)

Answer (score 9):

You can use the RotateTransform and TranslateTransform that are available on the Graphics class. Because using DrawString is GDI+ the transforms affects the drawing. So use something like this...

```
g.RotateTransform(45f);
g.DrawString("My String"...);
g.RotateTransform(-45f);
```

Don't forget to reverse the change though!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function.

```
   void DrawDigonalString(Graphics G, string S, Font F, Brush B, PointF P, int Angle)
   {
       SizeF MySize = G.MeasureString(S, F);
       G.TranslateTransform(P.X + MySize.Width / 2, P.Y + MySize.Height / 2);
       G.RotateTransform(Angle);
       G.DrawString(S, F, B, new PointF(-MySize.Width / 2, -MySize.Height / 2));
       G.RotateTransform(-Angle);
       G.TranslateTransform(-P.X - MySize.Width / 2, -P.Y- MySize.Height / 2);
   }
```

Like this

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! But how can I determine the width of the angled text? e.g. if I have a string width of 50. After rotating the text, it'll take less width...

Answer (score 0):

u have right..It can be done in that way..BUT text will be written from top to bottom always and I'm not sure u can change it from bottom to top.. cheers

Answer (score -1):

There is another way to draw a text vertically which is built in the C#. There is no need of explicit graphics transformation. You can use the StringFormat class. Here is a sample code which draws a text vertically:

StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
   sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical;
   e.Graphics.DrawString("My String", this.Font, Brushes.Black, PointF.Empty, sf);